# What is exactly the difference between an active and passive frequency standard?

Tags: atomic-physics, atomic-clocks

In the case of passive atomic frequency standard, we take an atomic reference which has a resonant frequency response centered at certain particular frequency. Then we take a local oscillator and tune its frequency to  that particular frequency using certain servo control mechanisms. Then to convert this atomic standard to a clock we count the oscillations of local oscillator that is stabilised.

However, I don't understand what an active atomic frequency standard is. Is there some difference about how the atoms get excited in both these cases? Is it that in case of active the excitation of atoms takes place by itself and in case of passive we need an external power source to continuously excite the atoms?

Answer (score 2):

In a passive system, you create the frequency externally by some means, then perturb it and check if the quality of that frequency is improved or degraded.  In the case of the cesium clock, you see if the fraction of the ions that shift under the reference beam increases or decreases.

In the active system, there is no external frequency signal.  Instead the frequency is generated inside the system, amplified, and either measured or used to drive another oscillator (probably one that is very damped) that is measured.